# Are Catholic Bishops the successors of the Apostles alone or the Elders too?

Tags: catholicism, early-church, elders, bishops

In researching my answer for [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/does-catholicism-confound-the-role-of-elder-and-priest) I started to think about the doctrine that the Bishops are the successors of the Apostles as being a bit unfair to the other folks. For instance, if St. James who wrote the epistle wasn't the brother of John or Jude, but actually a third James or a fourth James who was the Bishop of Jerusalem, would his Episcopacy necessarily have been conferred on him by the Apostles or just by virtue of who he was. Or were the elders the first successors of the 12 apostles regardless of their functions as presbyters?

Answer (score 4):

The answer you seek is here: [Bishops Are Successors of the Apostles](http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/john_paul_ii/audiences/alpha/data/aud19920708en.html) | General Audience of Pope St. John Paul II [the Great], [*8 July 1992*](http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/john_paul_ii/audiences/1992/index_en.htm).

---

- "Presbyters" (= elders cf. [Priest | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12406a.htm)), first subordinate rank of the hierarchy, were among the "various helpers" who assisted the Apostles in their ministry.
- From the article, that the Bishops are the successors to the Apostles, is in this sentence, quoting the Second Vatican Council:

> The Council says: "Thus, as St. Irenaeus testifies, through those who
>   were appointed bishops by the apostles, and through their successors
>   down in our own time, the apostolic tradition is manifested and
>   preserved <sup>1</sup> " (LG 20).
>
> <sup>1. St. Irenaeus, Adv. Haer., III, 3, 1; cf. Tertullian, De
>   Praescr., 20, 4-8: PL 2, 32; CC 1, 202</sup>

Answer (score -1):

As St. Jerome points out, in terms of their spiritual, divinely-appointed, office, all priests (presbyters) are bishops (episcopes) and have the same dignity. In terms, however, of Church custom, for the sake of necessary prevention of corruption and schism, all responsibility is delegated to a sort of archbishop (but, still, just called a bishop). It works much like the presidency. The power--in this case the spiritual, apostolic succession--truly lies with, and is derived from, the people (the priests/presbyters), but it is placed in the President (the bishop/episcope). The priests can take it back, the priests are not lesser (the bishop being a "first among equals"), and some bishops are not even legitimate, though validly ordained.

> Therefore, as **the presbyters know that it is by the custom of the Church that they are to be subject to him who is placed over them so let the bishops know that they are above presbyters rather by custom than by Divine appointment**, and ought to rule the Church in common, following the example of Moses, who, when he alone had power to preside over the people Israel, chose seventy, with the assistance of whom he might judge the people. **We see therefore what kind of presbyter or bishop should be ordained**.

--Jerome, Commentary on Titus 26:563

> If so, then listen to the blast of the gospel trumpet, that son of thunder, Mark 3:17 the disciple whom Jesus loved John 13:23 and who reclining on the Savior's breast drank in the waters of sound doctrine. One of his letters begins thus: "**The presbyter** unto the elect lady and her children whom I love in the truth;" and another thus: "**The presbyter** unto the well-beloved Gaius whom I love in the truth." When subsequently one presbyter was chosen to preside over the rest, this was done to remedy schism and to prevent each individual from rending the church of Christ by drawing it to himself. For even at Alexandria from the time of Mark the Evangelist until the episcopates of Heraclas and Dionysius [c. A.D. 250] **the presbyters always named as bishop one of their own number chosen by themselves and set in a more exalted position**, just as an army elects a general, or as deacons appoint one of themselves whom they know to be diligent and call him archdeacon. For what function, excepting ordination, belongs to a bishop that does not also belong to a presbyter? It is not the case that there is one church at Rome and another in all the world beside. Gaul and Britain, Africa and Persia, India and the East worship one Christ and observe one rule of truth. **If you ask for authority, the world outweighs its capital. Wherever there is a bishop**, whether it be at Rome or at Engubium, whether it be at Constantinople or at Rhegium, whether it be at Alexandria or at Zoan, **his dignity is one and his priesthood is one**. Neither the command of wealth nor the lowliness of poverty makes him more a bishop or less a bishop. **All alike are successors of the apostles**. ... Of the names presbyter and bishop the first denotes age, the second rank. **In writing both to Titus and to Timothy the apostle speaks of the ordination of bishops and of deacons, but says not a word of the ordination of presbyters; for the fact is that the word bishops includes presbyters also**.

--Jerome, Letter 146: To Evangelus

> **No difference is made between a priest and a bishop (presbyterum et episcopum); the same dignity belongs to the sender and the sent**...

--Jerome, To Pammachius Against Joannem Hierosolymitanum, §37, 23:390

> Our apostles also knew, through our Lord Jesus Christ, that there would be strife on account of the office of the **episcopate**. For this reason, therefore, inasmuch as they had obtained a perfect fore-knowledge of this, they appointed those [ministers] already mentioned, and afterwards gave instructions, that **when these should fall asleep**, **other approved men should succeed them in their ministry**. We are of opinion, therefore, that **those appointed by them, or afterwards by other eminent men, with the consent of the whole church**, and who have blamelessly served the flock of Christ, in a humble, peaceable, and disinterested spirit, and have for a long time possessed the good opinion of all, **cannot be justly dismissed from the ministry**. **For our sin will not be small, if we eject from the episcopate those who have blamelessly and holily fulfilled its duties. Blessed are those presbyters who, having finished their course before now, have obtained a fruitful and perfect departure [from this world];** for they have no fear lest any one deprive them of the place now appointed them. But we see that you have removed some men of excellent behavior from the ministry, which they fulfilled blamelessly and with honor.

--Clement, First Letter to the Corinthians, Chapter 44

> This is why I left you in Crete, that you might amend what was defective, and **appoint elders [presbyters]** in every town as I directed you, if any man is blameless, the husband of one wife, and his children are believers and not open to the charge of being profligate or insubordinate. For **a bishop [episcope]**, as God’s steward, must be blameless; he must not be arrogant or quick-tempered or a drunkard or violent or greedy for gain, but hospitable, a lover of goodness, master of himself, upright, holy, and self-controlled;

--Titus 1:5-8 (RSV)

Comment: The question is tagged "Catholicism" and is clearly asking about the Catholic doctrine of Apostolic Succession, thus your selective quoting from the Church Fathers with your own conclusions does not answer the question.

Comment: @eques - Since tradition is important in Catholicism, he's questioning the doctrine of Bishops as the sole successors of the Apostles (not just asking what the Catholic teaching is), and he also inquired as to whether presbyters have the dignity of being successors of the Apostles as well, I gave both an eminent Church Father--Jerome (e.g., "All alike are successors of the apostles.")--and a Biblical text that shows that presbyters have the exact same succession. [Continued in Next Comment]

Comment: Another relevant fact I gave is that, as it is clear that Apostolic Succession applies to all presbyters, so too is it clear that it is Church custom that presbyters are to be subject to the bishops placed over them (e.g., "the presbyters know that it is by the custom of the Church that they are to be subject to him who is placed over them so let the bishops know that they are above presbyters rather by custom than by Divine appointment") in order to help prevent schism. All that I said was directly relevant and was a good answer, and it was not just cherry picking as you suggest.

Comment: On the contrary, my point stands. The fact that Catholic Church doesn't teach that bishops and presbyters are the same shows that there is more to the picture than the quote from Jerome. This is a common error when dealing with Patristics especially by non-Catholics. The Church Fathers have to be read less so as individuals and more as a collection; that is, individuals say things which appear to support one doctrine or another, but when compared against other Fathers it is apparent that either that text cannot be read in that way or that the weight of the Church is a different way.

Comment: @eques - He is thinking about, or concerning, the Catholic doctrine. He is not asking what the Catholic doctrine is. With all due respect, to claim that giving any response that isn't just quoting the Catholic doctrine "does not answer the question" is just incorrect. I answered the question, just not the way you prefer. It is a fact that bishops were, disregarding what is now, elected by presbyters from among themselves, and it is a fact that Apostolic Succession belonged, at least at first, to both presbyters and bishops. If you wish to keep asserting I'm wrong, then please provide evidence.

Comment: I didn't say "just quoting Catholic doctrine" If you are goin to accuse me of supporting my own preferences, at least quote me accurately. Yet again, the point I made stands. You reference 2 Church fathers as though their interpretations were uniform in their days. You did not for example attempt trace why those are distinct or when that occurred. Nor do you comment on "Successor of the Apostles" which is definitely part of the question.

Comment: And Catholicism is definitely revenant to the question (and lacking in your answer) and not because "it's not according to my preference) but by the rules of the site, the use of the tag and by the fact the Catholic doctrine "successor of the apostles" is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @eques - The tag means that it concerns the Catholic Doctrine, as far as I can tell, not that one can only answer by quoting the Catholic doctrine. I am talking about the Catholic doctrine, namely, that bishops are the sole successors of the apostles; however, that doesn't limit me to putting what the doctrine is, especially since that is what he already gave (i.e., "the doctrine that the Bishops are the successors of the Apostles") and is questioning if it is unfair to presbyters. One last time, I'm talking about the Catholic doctrine, and directly answering his questions, so I'm on topic.

Comment: Again, I've never said you had to quote Catholic doctrine. I said you have to answer according to Catholic doctrine. And yours is factually inaccurate when it comes to Catholic doctrine. The point of the "Catholicism" tag is so that people can get information as it relates to Catholicism, not what someone else things Catholics should do or may have done or ought to believe. And no, you didn't answer whether it's unfair -- you speculate things which are definitely not Catholic doctrine. Hence my -1 remains.

Comment: @eques - Since you are going to keep making this assertion, can you please provide evidence that the tag "Catholicism" means that you have to answer according to the doctrine rather than that the issue and its answers pertain to the Catholic doctrine? He's questioning the Catholic doctrine. "The point of the "Catholicism" tag is so that people can get information as it relates to Catholicism, not what someone else things Catholics should do or may have done or ought to believe." "Relates" being the key word. Show me where he asked if it was unfair, please. That wasn't his question. (Continued)

Comment: @eques - (Contrinued) I dealt with the heart of his question, which is expressed at the end: "Or were the elders the first successors of the 12 apostles regardless of their functions as presbyters?" His question wasn't if the Catholic doctrine is fair; rather, his thought about the Catholic doctrine is that it seems to be unfair which leads to his question. You can leave your -1, that's your prerogative, but it's quite clear that it's either due to your bias or your failure to understand the original question and/or my answer that you do so.